# How to set CSS Source Map output destination when grunt-contrib-less is used

Tags: gruntjs, less, grunt-contrib-less

I am using grunt-contrib-less for compiling less files.

I have grunt locally installed at root of project folder.

The css files are located at `qa1/avinash/html5/phase1/css/` path from root of project folder.

So this is the path i am specifying for `cwd` (current working directory), `src` and `dest` parameters of the grunt-less task. there are no issues in compilation of css and source map.

The only issue i face is that the source map is generated in the same folder of gruntfile. but my generated css is at the `dest` path i specified. since the css and source map are at different locations i have to manually edit the less path references in source map and bring it to the generated css directory. or use `sourceMapURL` to specify the source map location `../../../../../style.css.map`(backwards). Both ways are not convenient.

So can anyone help me how to specify the **source map output destination path** like we specify for destination path for generated css something like

```
sourceMapDest: 'qa1/avinash/html5/phase1/css/'
```

--

currently used **Gruntfile.js:**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        less: {
            options: {
                sourceMap:true,
                sourceMapFilename: "style.css.map",
                sourceMapURL: '../../../../../style.css.map'
            },
            src: {
                // no need for files, the config below should work
                expand: true,
                cwd:    "qa1/avinash/html5/phase1/css/",
                src:    "style.less",
                dest:   "qa1/avinash/html5/phase1/css/",
                ext:    ".css"
            }
        },
        watch: {
            js: {
                files: ['qa1/avinash/html5/phase1/css/'],
                tasks: ['default'],
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['less']);
};
```

Comment: Just use this path for the `sourceMapFilename` option? I.e. `sourceMapFilename: "your_path_of_interest\style.css.map"`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Thanks a lot, it worked. Please mention it as an answer instead of a comment. I will upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sourceMapFilename` option may include a path part as well.
I.e. just change it to:

```
sourceMapFilename: "qa1/avinash/html5/phase1/css/style.css.map"
```